# Application to switch between defined set of windows?

Tags: windows

I have a few different windows (not programs, but windows... a few from 2 different applications) that I must switch between constantly. of course I also have many other windows open.

However, I just want to select somehow or define somehow these 3 or 4 windows and then press a key to cycle between those windows.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally!**

after a lot of searching, I found a great little program. It doesn't even have an installer.

Wilma: Windows Layout Manager

http://www.snapfiles.com/get/wilma.html

it's very configurable

just in case anyone else is looking for this kind of thing

and also I will configure Strokes Plus (best windows gesture management utility) to switch layouts for me; this can be accomplished by calling wilma from the commandline

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into virtual desktops.  This will give you multiple separate desktop areas on each of which you can organize your windows however you like. You can then switch back and forth between these desktops with a hotkey.

I haven't used virtual desktops in MS Windows for quite some time so i can't make a personal recommendation on a good pruduct, but here is a quick rundown of a few from a relatively recent article -- Some of them are even free and well reviewed: http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/how-to-get-virtual-desktops-in-windows.html

Comment: thanks, I'm familiar with some virtual desktop tools but was wondering if there was another way.. since I prefer to keep everything on one desktop. and also I have dual monitors and prefer to keep what is displayed on the 2nd monitor visible at all times.